# CardView styling not showing on device

Tags: runtime, cardview

I am trying to make a custom style for a cardview on my activity. It works just as I want to in Android Studio. But when I run it on my device - Galaxy S7 Edge android 7.0 - the cardview attributes are not changing. It uses the background from the style of the layout, and the rest of the attributes - elevation, corner radius and card background seem to be ingnored.
I dont get any errors in the log.

The layout uses `style="@style/AddItemStyle"`

The card uses `style="@style/AddItemStyle.CardView"`

Thats the card style

```
<style name="AddItemStyle.CardView" parent="CardView">
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/card_bg</item>
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">15dp</item>
    <item name="cardElevation">15dp</item>
</style>
```

Thats the layout style

```
<style name="AddItemStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/mySecondary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ColorMain</item>
    <item name="editTextColor">@color/ColorMain</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/mySecondary</item>
</style>
```

[In android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiZRX.png)

[On my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUhAJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason removing `android:theme="@style/AddItemStyle"` from the activity in manifest fixed the problem. I don't know why but it worked.